# OpenCV build on Windows Visual Studio error: 'setlocal' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015, build, cmake

I am building OpenCV source code on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015, but encounter an strange error.
First of all, I configured the source code with CMake. After configuration successfully done, I opened the configured OpenCV solution with VS2015 and press F7 to build. However, seems that every project being built encounter following error caused by 'setlocal' is not recognized.

```
6>------ Build started: Project: IlmImf, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
6>  'setlocal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
6>  operable program or batch file.
```

Things are strange because previously I also built OpenCV source code on Win10 with VS2015 and there was no any such kind of error before. But not know why this error appears now.

How do resolve this error?

Comment: What exact version of OpenCV is it?

Comment: @DanMašek, I pull out the latest OpenCV code on github, should be version at 3.4.1

Comment: Did you check out the latest stable tag, or just grab the master (which is in development)?

Comment: @DanMašek, actually, I checked out the master (development) on github instead of the stable tag. But I did the same thing on my other laptops and seems that on those machines, no such kind of issue appears. Also, I have uninstalled VS2015 and install VS2017 to have a try, the same issue still exists.

Comment: Just tested on the stable version of 3.4.1, still has such kind of issue, seems that it is my environment cause this problem, but currently I do not have any idea how could I find the root cause...

Comment: Thanks for the update -- being on the stable version at least puts us all on the same page, and eliminates the uncertainty that something may have gotten broken during the development process. | Looks related, no real solution there tho: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16824

Comment: Yes... the guy asked the same question on the link you provided is me... And in that thread, seems that person kept this issue away because he installed VS2017, according to his description. However, mine is still there after I changed the installation from VS2015 to VS2017. So, I guess it might be caused by my system environment. I will keep on checking. Finally, thank you so much for providing the information!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and update it with info on whether you a) started with a clean build, and b) what exact command(s) you used to generate the solution with CMake? Try to give as much detail as possible that would allow someone to reproduce the problem.